# React-Admin: How can i get value of custom input inside 'Create' or 'Edit' Component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

For the past days i've been searching for a way to get the value of my custom input component in the parameters of the create/edit component.

I created the component following Material UI's example in this [link](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/#react-autosuggest)

The component is rendered in the application but i can't get the value of the input. Here's how I add the custom input

`<Create><SimpleForm>
...
<CustomAutocompleteInput label="Main Subject" suggestions={subjectSuggestions} source="mainSubject"/>
...
</SimpleForm></Create>`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's your usecase ?

Comment: @Gildas I'm trying to create an autosuggest input that accepts texts different from the options listed. the actual AutocompleteInput that react-admin gives does not provide it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code of the `CustomAutocompleteInput` ? Can't help you otherwise. The best would be a codesandbox.io

Answer (score 0):

you can set a reference to the dom node

```
<CustomAutocompleteInput 
    ref={node => {this.input = node;}}
    label="Main Subject" 
    suggestions={subjectSuggestions} 
    source="mainSubject"
/>
```

...and then access the value by

```
let { value } = this.input

//or
let value = this.input.value
```